# React native android app build getting failed: Error: Plugin 0 specified

Tags: android, react-native

While taking build on android emulator the build is getting failed every time by showing the following error , but showing build successful with error in emulator.Following is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "AppReact",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to find error in index.js.

Comment: But  in `index,js` it contains `'use strict';

module.exports = require('./configs/main');
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change from

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "5",
```

to

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
```

in package.json file 
and then just run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-add babel preset.

```
yarn remove babel-preset-react-native
yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

If you are using npm use this.

```
npm uninstall babel-preset-react-native
npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

[Ref](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15513)

Comment: Tried this too..but getting `unexpected token const. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode`.

Comment: If you are just testing then try init different project.

Comment: hm..no use i tried by creating new projects but still getting same error.

Comment: That's strange, i never get these types of errors in fresh project.

Comment: Yes..for me also its the first time i'm getting an error like this.I had done different apps in react native before.But the thing is i upgraded my os (windows 10) so i had to install all (android studio, react native, node, java ) from the beginning.After that i'm getting issues like this for newly creating apps, but the old ones are working perfectly.

Comment: I just solved this by downgrading both RN and react-native-babel-preset versions.Anyway thank you.